# ng-click expression in view setting $scope.var's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  <button ng-click="showText==true">Click</button>
  <p ng-show="showText">my p</p>
```

I don't want to go the the controller.js to set showText equal to true to show the `p` why above shortcut doesn't work?

Comment: `showText==true` is comparing and `showText=true` is assigning

Comment: use `showText=!showText` for toggling..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `=`(assignment operator) instead of `==` (comparison operator)

`==` is doing comparison instead of assigning value to showText.

**Markup**

```
<button ng-click="showText=true">Click</button>
  <p ng-show="showText">my p</p>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/U99GGHk5hpDDop69FpiE?p=preview)

Hope it help :)